# neighbors fence is protruding on my side and I want to build a new fence

Tags: fence

I bought a house a few years back. There is a chain link fence in the backyard. It is basically a rectangle design with the bottom of the rectangle being the back of my house which the fence is not on.

The fence on the right side is not a chain link fence but some poorly put wooden fence with the posts on my side and the fencing on the neighbors side. This is only for 1 side the rest is chain link. I have contacted my county to get a survey out to see it and they said it will be another month. I do want to also mention that the neighbor's house also has the same type of chain link fence; it's just at the middle connection in the backyard that has this weird setup. My other neighbor has a wooden fence that is right next to my chain link fence.

How do I go about addressing this?

Comment: You've got two very different questions. The first one (survey, neighbor's fence on your property) is probably a better fit for [Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com) The second (pieces vs. pre-made sections) is potentially a good fit for DIY SE, but need more specifics - what type of wood, how tall, does the fence cover any change in elevation (so sections would need to be cut to fit), etc.

Comment: The second question "is it better" is a matter of opinion that would get it closed. If you were to ask the Pros/Cons of A vs B, you'll likely get good answers. That said, _you_ can hire your own survey company to come out and figure out where the actual property lines are. However, it's highly likely that you won't be able to _force_ your neighbors to move an existing fence. There are laws that protect owners from retroactive issues like this. If it's egregious, you may have grounds to stand on, but if it's a matter of feet or inches, most likely not. (con't)

Comment: ... If it's found that any of the fences are into your property, you might be able to work _with_ your neighbors to get the fence moved, sharing the costs (get it in writing before starting work). I'm honestly not sure what your actual question is, how do you go about addressing _what_? Maybe give us a drawing and show us exactly what the issue is, as your word description leaves me a bit confused...

Comment: *"posts on my side and the fencing on the neighbors side"* In the UK this would indicate it is **your** fence, not theirs - but it's always best to negotiate with the neighbours rather than just make a unilateral move.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and ask just one question per post. I removed the second question. You should not re-ask it in comments.  I agree that we'd need more information to help with the actual fence problem. Neighbor disputes are off topic here.

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly?  I think it is: the chain link fence belongs to you and is on your property and you want to replace it.  On one side your neighbor has a wood fence ? That is on your property?  If it is on your property how is it their fence and not yours?  Or if it's not on your property why is it a problem, you can just build your new fence next to it.

Comment: If you really want the new fence, talk to your neighbour, tell them you will bear the costs for the new fence, the surveying to make sure its in the correct place and fir demo of the old fence

Comment: Seconding @Tetsujin 's comment above - In many areas you're required to build your fence such that if it has a 'good' side and a 'bad' side, then the 'good' side must face 'outwards' away from your property, towards the public and/or neighbors. So your description of where the posts are and how it's facing strongly makes it seem that this is in fact *your* fence and not your neighbor's fence.

Comment: In Dallas TX where I live surveys are done at the expense of the property owner wanting it. Some survey companies will provide a partial survey at a reduced price to establish one property line for the purpose of placing fencing. It is a good idea to have the property line well established because if there is an encroachment then it could complicate future transfer of property.

Comment: @brhans Where I live 6 ft tall wooden "privacy" fences are the norm and many people go insane with 8' or 10' fences which are supposed to require preapproval by code enforcement but code enforcement doesn't care unless there is a complaint. The practice is that the good side always faces out to the street in front, the back side always faces the alley in back, and the back side usually faces the neighbor's property on the side.  When we got one 35 years ago my wife had the good side out everywhere so it couldn't be easily climbed from the outside (by humans or coyotes).

Answer (score 1):

If the neighbors are reasonable they might be willing to allow their old fence to be removed to allow you to place your fence with the posts and the panels on your property. The benefit to them would be that they get the use of a new fence along their property line that will be maintained by someone else. Of course, that means they do not get to choose the type of fence, color or stain or paint, etc. You might tell them what types and colors of stains you are considering and ask them if they have a preference.

You would be placing your posts in line with the existing posts (which you say is on your property) and putting the "front" side of the fence toward your yard. If their fence were removed, they would be looking at the "back" side of your fence which would probably be nicer in appearance than the front side of their old fence.

One question I have about fences right next to the property line is if the outsides of the poles are right at the property line, and they are set in concrete, then the concrete filled holes will extend across the property line  by 4" or so. Could this be legitimately considered an encroachment? If the neighbors were reasonable, the neighbors should not treat this as an encroachment, but sometimes people are not reasonable.

I say go talk to your neighbors about this. If you do, don't disparage their old fence. They might have an emotional attachment to it depending on whether it was a pet project, maybe constructed by some beloved relative who has since passed.

Most people nowadays use circular cross section hollow metal poles, but there are other possibilities. One new type of metal fence pole has an open cross section with two wings. [Master Halco](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Master-Halco-Common-3-1-2-in-x-3-1-2-in-x-7-1-2-ft-Actual-3-5-in-x-3-625-in-x-7-5-ft-Galvanized-Steel-Galvanized-Steel-Wood-Fence-Line-Post/3434930?cm_mmc=shp-_-b-_-prd-_-lum-_-ggl-_-LIA_LUM_000_PRO-_-3434930-_-local-_-0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA-P-rBhBEEiwAQEXhH7YPkiDl_tjpMGH7cZrH_z9iZEz5xaN0VtDju6QA3fmQDSkQW97oYxoCG98QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) is one brand. This type might possibly be able to be driven into the ground (with a vibrating driver) so no holes to dig and no concrete.

Another advantage of the Master Halco posts is that the fence could be built with horizontal slats and the back side of the fence would look as good as the front if the poles were boxed in. A horizontal fence however may be more expensive because horizontal slats have to thicker and a better grade and species of wood.

Comment: I'm going for the wooden picket fence, not sure what the metal pole is for. My neighbors just said it's cool if I remove their old one and replace it. I'll get this in writing.

Comment: Where is this property located--state and at least county? Is this rural, semi-rural, suburban, or urban?

Comment: Are you planning a "privacy" fence 6 ft or taller? Or are you planning an open picket fence with 2 or 3 inches between the pickets?

Comment: College park Maryland.  8ft tall. It will be premade